# How call a method on all step of class derivation hierarchy?

Tags: c++, casting

Take this example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeindex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class _IEventHandler {}; // just for abstract template type

class IEvent {
public:
  virtual void visitEventHandler(_IEventHandler *handler) = 0;
};

#define EXTENDS(type, parentType) \
public: \
  using ParentClass = parentType; \
  void visitEventHandler(_IEventHandler* handler) override { \
    static_cast<IEventHandler<type>*>(handler)->on(*this); \
  } \


template<typename Event>
class IEventHandler : public _IEventHandler {
public:
  //virtual void on(Event& e) = 0;
  void on(Event &e) {
    std::cout << "handle " << typeid(Event).name() << std::endl;
  }
};

class EventA : public IEvent {
EXTENDS(EventA, IEvent)
};

class EventB : public EventA {
EXTENDS(EventB, EventA)
};

class EventC : public EventB {
EXTENDS(EventC, EventB)
};

class EventD : public EventC {
EXTENDS(EventD, EventC)
};

class EventBus {
public:
  void fire(IEvent *event) {
    while (typeid(*event) != typeid(IEvent)) {
      for (_IEventHandler *handler : m_handlers[typeid(*event)])
        event->visitEventHandler(handler);
      // Need to update event so the loop progresses. Need to upper cast?
    }
  }

  template<typename T>
  void hook(IEventHandler<T> *handler) {
    m_handlers[typeid(T)].push_back(handler);
  }

protected:
  std::map<std::type_index, std::vector<_IEventHandler *>> m_handlers{};
};

int main() {
  EventBus eb{};

  IEventHandler<EventD> ehd{};
  IEventHandler<EventC> ehc{};
  IEventHandler<EventA> eha{};

  eb.hook(&ehd);
  eb.hook(&ehc);
  eb.hook(&eha);

  EventD eD{};
  EventB eB{};

  eb.fire(&eD); // need to stdout handle EventD   handle EventC   handle EventA
  eb.fire(&eB); // need to stdout handle EventA

  return 0;
}
```

I would like when I fire a IEvent it call `on(EventX& e)` on all intermediate derived class and stop on abstract class IEvent.

Currently I don't find solution, I looked about dyn_cast with a typeid, using decltype to access a static method from a instance (yes it's not the basic usage of these operators ;) and not permitted).

---

**Summary:**
The goal is to build an event system that supports hooking handlers and firing events. Events are hierarchical, deriving from a common ancestor class. Handlers should be called for their nominal event type and all types derived from that.

So far, the `EventBus` class is able to call handlers for the specific event type that was fired. The handlers are organized in a `map` from `type_index` to a `vector` of handlers. Getting the entry for a specific event type is not a problem, but how to get the less-derived types?

Comment: `_IEventHandler` is not a valid name to create in user code. And this sounds  like an XY problem.

Comment: There's no such thing in C++. Typically, each overriding virtual method will be responsible for calling the overridden method in the parent class.

Comment: Yes typically when we describe e type, but a Handler do not have known of other Handler but I want to have the possibility to handle EventB when EventD is fire.

For `_IEventHandler` no warning or error but it's just a sample code not the complete code that more complex. I can use also anonymous namespace to protect it of implementation in other namespace/class.

Comment: A class definitely knows all the classes it's inheriting from.

Comment: Yes all EventX knows it's parents class! But `IEventHandler<EventD>` do not know they need to pass the event to all `IEventHandler<EventC>` or `IEventHandler<EventB>` if none was hooked.

Comment: Your code has an infinite loop: `while (typeid(*event) != typeid(IEvent))` with no code to change `event`.

Comment: Thanks that why I leave a comment `// Need to upper cast`

Comment: That is very unclear. Casting does not change the `typeid` of a polymorphic object, so that is still not an attempt to change `event`. More explanation is needed if you want other people to understand what you are thinking. In fact, that could be said about the question overall. More explanation and less reliance on people deciphering your code. Especially since this is likely an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please take some time and write out what you think your code does.

Comment: My main goal is build a event system that we can hook some handlers and fire some event. Event is hierarchical ex: `IEvent -> InteractEvent -> IteractWithEntityEvent -> InteractWithEntityLivingEvent`. So what I want is when I fire a `InteractWithEntityLivingEvent` Handler that are listening for a `InteractWithEntityLivingEvent` are call on method `on(InteractWithEntityLivingEvent* e)` and up in hierarchy to call also `on(InteractEvent* e)` to Handlers listening `InteractEvent`. So this sample try to implement that.

Comment: @Hideman I meant that you should write our what you think your code does **in the question**, not in the comments. There is an "edit" link for a reason. Also, try writing more words and fewer things that get formatted as code. You already have the code snippet for your concrete example. (See also [ask].)

Comment: @Hideman I've edited the question to give you a better idea of the sort of explanation I would expect to see. (Although the explanation really should be before the code.) Feel free to revert it if I missed the point.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently solve my issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeindex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class _IEventHandler {}; // just for abstract template type

class IEvent {
public:
  virtual void visit_IEventHandler(std::type_index _index, _IEventHandler *handler) {}
  virtual std::type_index getParentTypeIndex(std::type_index index) {
    return typeid(IEvent);
  }
};

#define EXTENDS(type, parentType)                                         \
public:                                                                   \
  using Class = type;                                                     \
  using ParentClass = parentType;                                         \
  std::type_index getParentTypeIndex(std::type_index index) {             \
    if (index == typeid(type))                                            \
      return typeid(ParentClass);                                         \
    else                                                                  \
      return ParentClass::getParentTypeIndex(index);                      \
  }                                                                       \

#define HIERARCHICAL_VISITOR(interfaceType, reelType, methodName)         \
public:                                                                   \
  void visit##interfaceType(std::type_index _index, interfaceType* _instanceToVisit) override { \
    if (_index == typeid(Class))                                          \
      static_cast<reelType<Class>*>(_instanceToVisit)->methodName(*this); \
    else                                                                  \
      ParentClass::visit##interfaceType(_index, _instanceToVisit);        \
  }                                                                       \

template<typename Event>
class IEventHandler : public _IEventHandler {
public:
  //virtual void on(Event& e) = 0;
  void on(Event &e) {
    std::cout << "handle " << typeid(Event).name() << std::endl;
  }
};

class EventA : public IEvent {
EXTENDS(EventA, IEvent)
HIERARCHICAL_VISITOR(_IEventHandler, IEventHandler, on)
};

class EventB : public EventA {
EXTENDS(EventB, EventA)
HIERARCHICAL_VISITOR(_IEventHandler, IEventHandler, on)
};

class EventC : public EventB {
EXTENDS(EventC, EventB)
HIERARCHICAL_VISITOR(_IEventHandler, IEventHandler, on)
};

class EventD : public EventC {
EXTENDS(EventD, EventC)
HIERARCHICAL_VISITOR(_IEventHandler, IEventHandler, on)
};

class EventBus {
public:
  void fire(IEvent *event) {
    std::type_index index = typeid(*event);
    while (index != typeid(IEvent)) {
      for (_IEventHandler *handler : m_handlers[index])
        event->visit_IEventHandler(index, handler);
      index = event->getParentTypeIndex(index);
    }
  }

  template<typename T>
  void hook(IEventHandler<T> *handler) {
    m_handlers[typeid(T)].push_back(handler);
  }

protected:
  std::map<std::type_index, std::vector<_IEventHandler *>> m_handlers{};
};

int main() {
  EventBus eb{};

  IEventHandler<EventD> ehd{};
  IEventHandler<EventC> ehc{};
  IEventHandler<EventA> eha{};

  eb.hook(&ehd);
  eb.hook(&ehc);
  eb.hook(&eha);

  EventD eD{};
  EventB eB{};

  eb.fire(&eD); // need to stdout handle EventD   handle EventC   handle EventA
  eb.fire(&eB); // need to stdout handle EventA

  return 0;
}
/*
handle 6EventD
handle 6EventC
handle 6EventA
handle 6EventA

Process finished with exit code 0
*/
```

The only way that I found is use the basic inheritance process with the typeid check at all stage. I don't know if is the best way, I looking for a better way ;)

Answer (score 0):

The keywords for this answer are "**simplify**" and "**encapsulate**".

Let's start with simplifications. There are several elements of the question's code that serve no purpose other than making the code more complicated than it needs to be. (There might be a small performance benefit, but it is premature to worry about that.) In order to better see what the actual solution is, I think it is useful to include these improvements. On the other hand, these are only indirectly related to the actual solution, so I will refrain from giving a detailed rationale for each of these.

1. Rename `_IEventHandler` to `BaseEventHandler` to comply with naming requirements.
2. Make `on()` a virtual function in `BaseEventHandler` so that `visitEventHandler()` does not need a `static_cast`.
3. Make `visitEventHandler()` a non-virtual function since all implementations are now the same.

   - Declare `~IEvent()` to be virtual so that `IEvent` still has a virtual function.
4. Remove the `EXTENDS` macro because (*macros are evil* and) the things it defines are no longer used.

Moving on to encapsulation, let's look at the problem from the point of view of `EventBus`. This class is responsible for triggering handlers in response to events. It has inferred which event each handler wants, and organized the handlers by those event types. *This already breaks encapsulation a bit since the bus uses knowledge about the handler's innards.* Now they want me to also know about inheritance among the event types??? I need more information or you can go handle it yourself!

Since encapsulation encourages less information, rather than more, let's consider the other option: handle it yourself! Er, let the handlers decide if they want to handle an event. This simplifies `EventBus` since it no longer needs to be concerned about event types. Its `map` containing `vector`s can become a single `vector`, its `hook()` method no longer needs to be a template, and its `fire()` method can drop the loop that has been so difficult to implement. The trade-off is that the event handlers now need to examine the event types. Fortunately, `dynamic_cast` makes the check very simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class IEvent;


/* ** Event handler ** */

class BaseEventHandler {
public:
    virtual void on(IEvent &) = 0;
};

template<typename Event>
class IEventHandler : public BaseEventHandler {
public:
  void on(IEvent & e) override {
    // Only fire for events of the templated type.
    if ( dynamic_cast<Event *>(&e) )
      std::cout << "handle " << typeid(Event).name() << std::endl;
  }
};


/* ** Event ** */

class IEvent {
public:
  virtual ~IEvent() {} // To force run time type information (RTTI)
  void visitEventHandler(BaseEventHandler* handler)
  {
    handler->on(*this);
  }
};

class EventA : public IEvent {};
class EventB : public EventA {};
class EventC : public EventB {};
class EventD : public EventC {};


/* ** Event Bus ** */

class EventBus {
public:
  void fire(IEvent *event) {
      for (BaseEventHandler *handler : m_handlers)
        event->visitEventHandler(handler);
  }

  void hook(BaseEventHandler *handler) {
    m_handlers.push_back(handler);
  }

protected:
  std::vector<BaseEventHandler *> m_handlers{};
};

int main() {
  EventBus eb{};

  IEventHandler<EventD> ehd{};
  IEventHandler<EventC> ehc{};
  IEventHandler<EventA> eha{};

  eb.hook(&ehd);
  eb.hook(&ehc);
  eb.hook(&eha);

  EventD eD{};
  EventB eB{};

  std::cout << "Firing event D.\n";
  eb.fire(&eD); // need to stdout handle EventD   handle EventC   handle EventA
  std::cout << "\nFiring event B.\n";
  eb.fire(&eB); // need to stdout handle EventA

  return 0;
}
```

Some things to note about this approach:

1. Event handlers are fired in the order in which they were hooked. Previously, the order was handlers for the most derived class in the order they were hooked, followed by handlers for that class's direct parent in the order they were hooked, etc. If this is an important consideration, see my other answer.
2. There are still some issues with this code, but I am willing to chalk them up to being artifacts arising from the need to minimize the example.
3. There is no need to `#include <typeindex>`! This is good. I consider use of that header to be a yellow flag for design flaws. Better than a red flag (such as macros), but still an indication that maybe there's a better way to do things.

Comment: _"Make on() a virtual function in BaseEventHandler so that visitEventHandler() does not need a static_cast."_ But a static_cast is effectively free, and virtual calls are not. That decision looks deliberate, and reasonable, to me.

Comment: I do see the benefit of simpler code but I think you're failing to consider the performance impact of your solution. Then again, the impact may not be problematic. Only the OP can know.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if there's a measurable performance impact, that part could be revisited. A priori, simplifying code (and getting rid of a macro) trump premature optimization.

Comment: My point is that we do not know why the OP designed it this way, and your solution introduces slowdowns without mentioning it. Premature optimization is one thing but willfully degrading the performance of a program without telling anybody is not reasonable either.

Comment: Fine, I can acknowledge the performance impact. But it is definitely premature, as the OP admitted (in the comments) that the goal is to *build* an event system. Until the system is built and functioning, one cannot identify this indirection as a performance bottleneck.

Comment: People get a bit too hung up on the notion of premature optimisation. It's no excuse to build slow programs without good reason. However, your code is sufficiently cleaner that, _in this case_, it may be a good enough reason :)

Answer (score 0):

The keywords for this answer are "**simplify**" and "**delegate**".

Let's start with simplifications. There are several elements of the question's code that serve no purpose other than making the code more complicated than it needs to be. (There might be a small performance benefit, but it is premature to worry about that.) In order to better see what the actual solution is, I think it is useful to include these improvements. On the other hand, these are only indirectly related to the actual solution, so I will refrain from giving a detailed rationale for each of these.

1. Rename `_IEventHandler` to `BaseEventHandler` to comply with naming requirements.
2. Make `on()` a virtual function in `BaseEventHandler` so that `visitEventHandler()` does not need a `static_cast`.
3. Remove the `EXTENDS` macro because (*macros are evil* and) the things it defines either are no longer used or will be defined elsewhere.

Moving on to delegation, let's look at why `EventBus` has trouble traversing the inheritance tree of events. One reason is straight-forward: `EventBus` is not an event. Instead of trying to replicate the inheritance tree, let's use existing elements of the language. Instead of trying to deduce things about events, let's hand the problem off to someone who knows better, namely the event itself.

What I have in mind is a shift of responsibilities, basically shifting most of `EventBus::fire()` to the events' `visitEventHandler()`. Since each class knows its parent, it can invoke its parent's version of `visitEventHandler()`, stepping up the hierarchy until the end is reached. The trade-off is that the type of the `map` becomes public knowledge, rather than merely a private implementation detail of `EventBus`. Probably a fair trade.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeindex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class IEvent;


/* ** Event handler ** */

class BaseEventHandler {
public:
    virtual void on(IEvent &) = 0;
};

template<typename Event>
class IEventHandler : public BaseEventHandler {
public:
  void on(IEvent &) override {
    std::cout << "handle " << typeid(Event).name() << std::endl;
  }
};

using HandlerMap = std::map<std::type_index, std::vector<BaseEventHandler *>>;


/* ** Event ** */

class IEvent {
public:
  // This is not an actual event type, so there are no handlers to visit.
  virtual void visitEventHandlers(HandlerMap &) = 0;
};
// Need a definition for derived classes to call:
void IEvent::visitEventHandlers(HandlerMap &) {}

template<class Base>
class EventFrom : public Base {
public:
  void visitEventHandlers(HandlerMap & handlers) override
  {
    // Visit the handlers for this specific event type.
    for (BaseEventHandler *handler : handlers[typeid(EventFrom)])
      handler->on(*this);
    // Visit the handlers for the parent event type.
    Base::visitEventHandlers(handlers);
  }
};

using EventA = EventFrom<IEvent>;
using EventB = EventFrom<EventA>;
using EventC = EventFrom<EventB>;
using EventD = EventFrom<EventC>;


/* ** Event Bus ** */

class EventBus {
public:
  void fire(IEvent *event) {
    event->visitEventHandlers(m_handlers);
  }

  template<typename T>
  void hook(IEventHandler<T> *handler) {
    m_handlers[typeid(T)].push_back(handler);
  }

protected:
  HandlerMap m_handlers{};
};

int main() {
  EventBus eb{};

  IEventHandler<EventD> ehd{};
  IEventHandler<EventC> ehc{};
  IEventHandler<EventA> eha{};

  eb.hook(&ehd);
  eb.hook(&ehc);
  eb.hook(&eha);

  EventD eD{};
  EventB eB{};

  std::cout << "Firing event D.\n";
  eb.fire(&eD); // need to stdout handle EventD   handle EventC   handle EventA
  std::cout << "\nFiring event B.\n";
  eb.fire(&eB); // need to stdout handle EventA

  return 0;
}
```

Some things to note about this approach:

1. There is quite a bit of complexity used to make sure all event handlers for the most derived class are fired before any handlers for less derived classes. If this is not important, see my other answer.
2. There are still some issues with this code, but I am willing to chalk them up to being artifacts arising from the need to minimize the example.
3. There are no macros! (Macros are a red flag, indicating a likely design flaw.)
4. I would change the signature of `hook()` to `void hook(BaseEventHandler *handler)`. While this means changes like `eb.hook(&ehd)` to `eb.hook<EventD>(&ehd)`, it gives more freedom in defining your event handlers (no need for the `IEventHandler` template). Probably a good trade.